# matlab creating and plotting 3d points

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm trying to create a meshgrid of many many points and plotting it.
It is working this way:

```
for x=roadLeft:10:roadRight
    for y=0:10:50
       for z=0:10:roadTop
         points(1,i)= x;
         points(2,i)= y;
         points(3,i)= z;
         i=i+1;
      end
    end
end
plot3(points(1,:),points(2,:),points(3,:), '*b')
```

but this is ugly and I'm sure there's a way to do it with meshgrid.
I tried to do:

```
[X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(roadLeft:10:roadRight, 0:10:50,0:10:roadTop);
surf(X,Y,Z)
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
CData must be an M-by-N matrix or M-by-N-by-3 array

Error in graph3d.surfaceplot>localConstructor (line 136)
h = graph3d.surfaceplot(argin{:});

Error in graph3d.surfaceplot (line 7)
h = localConstructor(varargin{:});

Error in surf (line 101)
hh = double(graph3d.surfaceplot(args{:},'parent',parax));
```

what is the problem and how can I do it right?

Comment: `surf` plots a surface, but your `meshgrid` call defines a 3D volume. Is your question about plotting this generated grid or about using `meshgrid`? Please specify.

Comment: I don't want it to be a surface, just many many points according to the meshgrid

Comment: So is your question about plotting the points `meshgrid` created similarly to your previous `plot3` call?

Comment: yes exactly, creating the same output just with the meshgrid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line lets you plot the 3D points created by meshgrid:

```
plot3(X(:), Y(:), Z(:), '*b')
```